# ASP.NET over IIS only handles 1 async request at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asynchronous, freeze

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 Web API Application over IIS 8.5.

The server is an AWS EC2.

I have an `ActionFilter` that logs incoming request URL. So essentially it logs the first time the request "enters" my application.

I am issuing 2 request simultaneously (using Postman) and I see that my `ActionFilter` is not invoked my 1st request finishes.

Those request involve an **async-await** pattern over a DB query.

I did it twice:

- 2 request to the same URL with different parameters (it's a web-api
  application)
- 2 requests to different URL (hence different
  `ApiController`)

I am using the IIS "out-of-the-box" settings.

1. How can I approach this issue?
2. Which IIS configuration settings should I check?
3. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the async-await is not relevant, because the `ThreadPool` threads should be able to handle multiple synchronous calls, right?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to debug yourself and figure out where requests are blocked. Good starting point would be to replace all DB access with `await Task.Delay(10000);` and see if you have the same problem... Coming up with [MCVE] is critical for SO question to be answerable - so spend some time coming up with one.

Comment: Are you sure that the requests are both being sent at the same time? Maybe Postman is sequencing the requests?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that Postman/Chrome is sequencing the requests to the same domain.
So it's client side limitation only.

Issuing request from multiple machines caused the IIS to respond in parallel.

Thanks everyone!